# If I call a function which loads an already loaded package, do I occupy twice as much memory?

Tags: r, function, memory, package

Suppose I have

```
library(purrr)

big_data <- replicate(10, data.frame(rep(NA, 1e6), sample(c(1:8, NA), 1e6, T), 
                                     sample(250, 1e6, T)), simplify = F)
bd <- do.call(data.frame, big_data)
names(bd) <- paste0('X', seq_len(30))

source("find_missing_columns.r")

index <- find_missing_columns(bd)
```

where the content of `find_missing_columns.r` is

```
find_missing_columns <- function(dataframe){
  # find columns which are all NA in dataframe: returns a logical vector index
  library(purrr)

  all_na <- function(x) {all(is.na(x))}
  index <-  map_lgl(dataframe, ~ all(is.na(.)))

}
```

`purrr` is loaded twice, both in the main and in the function. Does this mean that, while running the function, twice as much memory is allocated for the same package? If this is the case, then packages should not be loaded in functions which I reuse across multiple programs. In other words, I should comment       `library(purr)` in `find_missing_columns.r`. However, this introduces an dangerous dependency: the called function will only work if `purrr` has been loaded by the caller. So, should I always use the `purrr::map_lgl` syntax inside a callable function, in order to **both** avoid unnecessary memory occupation **and** not introduce dependencies on the calling code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `library()` call adds the package to your search path which is session specific and not scope specific. You cannot privately load packages in a function. You can't load the same package more than once. Nothing happens if you call `library()` again with the same package name.

Generally putting `library()` inside a function call is not good form. Using the fully qualified name is better. Or if you need to test if a library is present you can use `require()`. Usually one would just have the `library()` once at the top of your code.

If you have a bunch of functions that you are sourcing from somewhere, you might want to think about making them a package instead so you can make the dependency on other packages more explicit.